# GitLens in VS Code: no inline blame info anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

After several updates, and installing other extensions like Error Lens, I noticed that GitLens stopped working. There is no blame information displayed at the line ends anymore. Error Lens continues working.
I'm not using the plus features and are not logged in to a GitLens+ account.
According to its documentation, the inline blame is not a plus feature and should work without subscription.
When installing Code on another computer and synchronizing the settings, GitLens worked for a short while and then the inline blame messages disappeared.

Is this a known issue? What can be the reason?

Edit: GitLens inline blame works in the diff editor, opened from the source control view. The blame is also displayed in the status bar, and "Toggle Line Blame" also works as expected.However, neither of them works when opening a file normally. No status bar message, no inline blame, toggle line blame has no effect. It's enabled in the configuration. Disabling all other extensions and leaving only GitLens enabled has no effect, either.

Comment: Does it work for you in the diff editor, if you click a file in source control? It works for me there, stopped working in the normal editors only.

Answer (score 18):

I've been struggling with the same issue, for some time, but finally found my solution.

Hope this helps.

#### you have to exit ZEN mode

Like this, find `zen` at the bottom of the vscode status bar

[image]

then Change to `Review Mode`

[image]

Comment: Your issue might be independent from mine. I guess you're not using virtual drives assigned to folders with the subst command? Created a ticket for gitlens and they confirmed that the issue is with the virtual drives. It's some intrinsic limitation in Code.

Answer (score 12):

Okay figured the root cause. It's connected to virtual drives assigned to folders with the subst command.

- Open the workspace through the virtual drive and then open a file for
  editing from Explorer or ctrl-p: no blame info.
- Open the workspace through the virtual drive, and then open a file
  from the Source Control view by right-click / Open File: inline blame
  works
- Open the workspace through the original long path (no virtual drive)
  and then open files in any way: inline blame works

It seems to be an issue in the recent versions of the extensions. I'm going to create a ticket for it.

Comment: If a ticket was created, please add a link to it.

Answer (score 6):

If inline blame of GitLens doesn't show anymore, I found it gets fixed if you create an empty file in the root of your repo called `.git-blame-ignore-revs`. This works for me on a MacBook.

I found the solution here: https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/1143#issuecomment-758947995

Comment: This is what worked for me on a MacBook too. No idea why on this particular project it works like this when on a different project it works without adding this file.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, the workorund was moving all my projects to C drive, I hope this pelps someone else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).